# Parameterize pytest lazy_fixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

I have two parameterized fixtures that are similar (fixture A and B). In addition to this, fixture B needs some additional information from another fixture (fixture C). I don't always want to create the object returned by fixture C, and that's why I want to keep A and B separated in the first place.

I also have a fourth fixture (D), which I want to run with either A or B, depending on the scenario.

I am able to run D with either A or B by using `pytest-lazy-fixtures`, but I am not able to parameterize them. I have also tried to use `request.getfixturevalue` and looked at `pytest-cases`, but still not able to parameterize A or B. Is there any (elegant) way to do it? I am open to try other packages and design patterns - no special requirement to use `lazy_fixture`.

The code is similar to this:

```
import pytest
from pytest_lazyfixture import lazy_fixture


@pytest.fixture()
fixture_c():
  ...


@pytest.fixture()
fixture_a(request):
  param1 = request.param["param1"]
  param2 = request.param["param2"]
  ...


@pytest.fixture()
fixture_b(fixture_c, request):
  param1 = request.param["param1"]
  param2 = request.param["param2"]
  ...


@pytest.fixture()
fixture_d(request):
  initial_fixture = request.param["initial_fixture"]
  ...


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "fixture_b, fixture_d",
    [
        pytest.param(
            {
                "param1": "abcd"
                "param2": "123"
            },
            {
                "initial_fixture": lazy_fixture("fixture_b")
            }
        )
    ],
    indirect=True,
)
def test_parameterize_fixtures(fixture_d):
  ...
```

Comment: Can you provide more details than just their signatures?  Like some example inputs and outputs?  Also what is your actual probleM?  Is it throwing an error when you try? What error?